# Are only linear transformations associative

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am teaching myself linear algebra and calculus from [Apostol Calculus Volume 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000078) and I find it very satisfying. Today I came came across theorem 2.5 in chapter *linear* transformations and matrices which states that:

> > If $T: U \to V, S: V \to W ,R: W \to X$ are three functions, then we have:
> >
> > $$R(ST)= (RS)T$$

Proof:

> > Both functions $R(ST)$ and $(RS)T$ have domain $U$ and values in $X$. For each $x$ in U, we have:
> >
> > $[R(ST)](x)= R[(ST)(x)]= R[S[T(x)]]$ and $[(RS)(T)](x)=(RS)[T(x)]=R[S[T(x)]]$

This is a very natural proof and I understand it. What I fail to grasp is the use of *linear* transformation and the structure of vector spaces in the proof. I mean it is not at all obvious where does the proof makes use of the axioms of linear transformation and vector spaces.

So is the theorem valid for non linear transformations and/or sets which are not vector spaces? If no, then please point out the assumptions of the proof and its scope.

Comment: The theorem says "functions," not "linear transformations." Indeed, function composition is associative, no matter whether the function is linear.

Comment: @symplectomorphic  Can I view linear transformations as functions?

Comment: yes, of course... a linear transformation is a specific type of function.

Comment: What about non linear transformations? I think they can also be viewed as functions which makes them associative as well. Am I correct?

Comment: not only are you correct, that's what I said in my first comment, and *that's what the theorem in Apostol's book says*. The only assumption of the theorem is that $R$, $S$, and $T$ are functions. It does not assume anything more about them (except that their domains and ranges are specified so that function composition makes sense). In particular, it does not assume they are linear transformations.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Okay this answers my question, if you make it an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem says "functions," not "linear transformations," so in fact the theorem Apostol proves answers your question: yes, function composition is associative, no matter whether the functions involved are linear. You are right to see that the proof doesn't depend in any way on linearity -- because, indeed, linearity is not assumed, nor is it needed.

Comment: Just a quick question, can I use the theorem to prove the associativity of matrix multiplication?  If it is possible, then it would save me a lot of computations which seem artificial.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the core reason is that:

- functions between *sets* are associative in the same sense as above.
- "a linear transformation is what a linear transformation does", which is to say that a linear transformation is completely determined by where it sends each element of its domain.

[Category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) is a subject that is good at formalizing answers to questions of this sort, I encourage you to look it up.

Comment: I am studying introductory linear algebra so perhaps category theory is out of question.

Comment: I think the definition of linear transformation that you provided also holds for functions.